# cannot log in to google with selenium webdrive

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

so i want to automate a specific scenario where i have to access gmail. but unfortunately once i enter the email address the following error appears.

[[image]]

in text:
Couldn’t sign you in
This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more
Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can try again to sign in.

what can i do to get past this error ? and there is another gmail address i use but i can logged in to that account without any issue but i cant use that address to my purpose

tried using a different browser(edge) but still the issue presents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bypass bot detection with [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) in `uc` mode.

First `pip install seleniumbase`. Then you can run:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True) as sb:
    sb.open("https://www.google.com/gmail/about/")
    sb.click('a[data-action="sign in"]')
    sb.type('input[type="email"]', "test123@gmail.com")
    sb.click('button:contains("Next")')
    sb.sleep(5)
    # sb.type('input[type="password"]', PASSWORD)
    # sb.click('button:contains("Next")')
```

Update the script with the info you need, then run with `python`. To access the raw driver from the script, use `sb.driver`.

Answer (score 0):

**I had this problem after too many tests, i just passed it with that way :**

```
import selenium.webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import random
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium_stealth import stealth

def get_random_language():
    languages = ["en-US", "en", "fr", "es", "de", "ja"]  # Add more languages as needed
    return random.choice(languages)

def get_random_vendor():
    vendors = [
        "Google Inc.",
        "Mozilla Foundation",
        "Microsoft Corporation",
        "Apple Inc.",
        "Samsung Electronics",
        "IBM Corporation",
        "Facebook, Inc.",
        "Amazon.com, Inc.",
        "Twitter, Inc.",
        "Intel Corporation",
        "Oracle Corporation",
        "Adobe Systems Incorporated",
        "Netflix, Inc.",
        "PayPal Holdings, Inc.",
        "Salesforce.com, Inc.",
        "Uber Technologies, Inc."
    ]
    return random.choice(vendors)

def get_random_platform():
    platforms = [
        "Win32",
        "Linux x86_64",
        "Macintosh",
        "Android",
        "iOS",
        "Windows NT",
        "Ubuntu",
        "Fedora",
        "Chrome OS",
        "Raspbian",
        "FreeBSD",
        "OpenBSD",
        "Solaris",
        "PlayStation",
        "Xbox"
    ]
    return random.choice(platforms)

def get_random_webgl_vendor():
    webgl_vendors = [
        "Intel Inc.",
        "NVIDIA Corporation",
        "AMD",
        "ARM",
        "Qualcomm",
        "Apple Inc.",
        "Broadcom",
        "Imagination Technologies",
        "Vivante Corporation",
        "Mali Technologies"
    ]
    return random.choice(webgl_vendors)

def get_random_renderer():
    renderers = [
        "Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        "NVIDIA GeForce GTX",
        "AMD Radeon",
        "ARM Mali",
        "Qualcomm Adreno",
        "Apple A12 Bionic",
        "Broadcom VideoCore",
        "Imagination PowerVR",
        "Vivante GC Series",
        "Mali-G77",
        "Intel UHD Graphics",
        "AMD Radeon Pro",
        "NVIDIA Quadro"
    ]
    return random.choice(renderers)

def get_random_timezone():
    timezones = ['US/Pacific', 'US/Mountain', 'US/Central', 'US/Eastern', 'Canada/Pacific', 'Canada/Mountain', 'Canada/Central', 'Canada/Eastern']
    random_timezone = random.choice(timezones)
    return random_timezone

def get_random_window_size():
    width = random.randint(1024, 1920)
    height = random.randint(768, 1080)
    return f"{width}x{height}"


chrome_options = selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('start-maximized')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-plugins")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions-file-access-check")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
prefs = {'profile.managed_default_content_settings.images': 2, 'profile.managed_default_content_settings.video': 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"javascript.enabled": True})
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=' + get_random_window_size())
chrome_options.add_argument('--force-timezone=' + get_random_timezone())
driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
stealth(driver,
    languages=[get_random_language()],
    vendor=get_random_vendor(),
    platform=get_random_platform(),
    webgl_vendor=get_random_webgl_vendor(),
    renderer=get_random_renderer()
)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get('https://github.com/') # better to do here random website function
driver.implicitly_wait(time_to_wait=10)
time.sleep(1)
driver.execute_script('''window.open("https://www.google.com/intl/en/gmail/about/","_blank");''')
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
driver.close()
driver.implicitly_wait(time_to_wait=10)
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
driver.implicitly_wait(time_to_wait=10)
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element('xpath','//* [@data-action=\'sign in\']').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(time_to_wait=10)
driver.find_element('id','identifierId').send_keys('email')
driver.find_element('id','identifierNext').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(time_to_wait=10)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)  # Maximum wait time of 10 seconds
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "Passwd")))
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element('name','Passwd').send_keys('password')
driver.find_element('id','passwordNext').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(time_to_wait=10)
# Your code here
```