# Gmail error : Couldn’t sign you in Using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, gmail

Gmail error : Couldn’t sign you in Using Selenium Java

Couldn’t sign you in
The browser you’re using doesn’t support JavaScript, or has JavaScript turned off.
To keep your Google Account secure, try signing in on a browser that has JavaScript turned on. Learn more

Tried to login gmail.com using Java in Selenium. But getting the above error

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Any other questions?

Comment: Check that solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76471550/cannot-log-in-to-google-with-selenium-webdrive/76483300#76483300

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

[image: Google_JavascriptEnable]

...implies that attempting to sign in with JavaScript disabled in your browser will result in facing the error, suggesting JavaScript either isn't supported by your browser or turned off.

---

### Solution

The only solution is to turn it back on or use a more modern browser.

You can check the *preferences* in [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) browser visiting the URL `about:config`:

[image: aboutConfig]