# Is it possible to avoid being detected by Gmail when using selenium automation?

Tags: python, email, selenium-webdriver, gmail

I want to automate logging in to my email in order to test my sites email verification system. But gmail detects that I am using selenium and prevents me from logging in to my account and says my browser is not secure. Is there a way to bypass this? Or is there another mainstream email service that does not detect selenium? I am using selenium webdriver on python

[image: selenium detection]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot log in to google with selenium webdrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76471550/cannot-log-in-to-google-with-selenium-webdrive)

Answer (score 0):

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76559073/7058266

You can use [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) in `uc` mode to bypass bot-detection.

First `pip install seleniumbase`. Then you can run:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True) as sb:
    sb.open("https://www.google.com/gmail/about/")
    sb.click('a[data-action="sign in"]')
    sb.type('input[type="email"]', "test123@gmail.com")
    sb.click('button:contains("Next")')
    sb.sleep(5)
    # sb.type('input[type="password"]', PASSWORD)
    # sb.click('button:contains("Next")')
```

Before starting, update the script with the info you need, and then run with `python`. To access the raw `driver` from the script, use `sb.driver`. [SeleniumBase has its own APIs](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/help_docs/method_summary.md) that you can use.

Comment: I implemented this code and it now logs in. But after I log in I am being redirected to a blank page. Is there a way to fix this