# This browser or app may not be secure (Selenium C#)

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-signin

I want to manually login to Google by navigating to the login page myself but the error `Couldn't sign you in, This browser or app may not be secure, Try using a different browser.` pops up. Here is what I have setup, nothing fancy.

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com/");
```

I could try and use the undetected selenium repo (https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/tree/master) but I would first like to see if I can do it in C#.

Any help on how to login to my google account from Selenium in C# would be much appreciated.

I tried using this code snippet but the Chrome tab will not even open, saying the following at line 4, and after that the program ends

`System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'An error occurred trying to start process 'C:\Users\name\source\repos\event_submitter\event_submitter\bin\Debug\net6.0\chromedriver.exe' with working directory 'C:\Users\name\source\repos\event_submitter\event_submitter\bin\Debug\net6.0'. The system cannot find the file specified.'`

```
1) var options = new ChromeOptions();
2) options.AddArguments(@"user-data-dir=c:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\");
3) IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
4) driver = new ChromeDriver(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), options);
5) driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com/");
```

Edit 1;
After adding the User-Agent header I noticed no difference so that wasn't helpful
`options.AddArgument("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25");`

Comment: add this `options.AddArgument("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25");`

Comment: To my first or to my second code snippet?

Comment: to both of them.

Comment: also download ChromeDriver.exe from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Comment: Neither code snippets worked after adding that argument you provided. Also I wish to only use selenium

Comment: Try this solution on C# probably it will works : [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76471550/cannot-log-in-to-google-with-selenium-webdrive/76483300#76483300)