# Google Sign in Using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, google-signin

This code is selenium 4 supported.
After opening the browser I try to sign menully but its not working.

the message is.

> This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more
> Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can try again to sign in.

**The solution I spect Loging Google account.**

This is the code:

[image]

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pathlib
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service


# chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:8797")
scriptDirectory = pathlib.Path().absolute()
# scriptDirectory = pathlib.PurePath("../driver")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
# chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=chrome-data")
chrome_options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
chrome_options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 8')
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=chrome-data")
# TODO: We have to solve the userdata problem it have to in one directory
chrome_options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={scriptDirectory}\\userdata")

service = Service(executable_path="C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\BasicGoogleContact\\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)


driver.get("https://basis.org.bd/company-profile/03-09-017")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
time.sleep(1)

contact_x_path = "//div[@class='card-body pt-0']"
contact_elements = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, contact_x_path)
contact_text = contact_elements.text
print(contact_text)

print("\n..........................")

footer_address_xpath = "//div[@class='footer-address']"
footer_address_elements = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, footer_address_xpath)
footer_address_text = footer_address_elements.text
print(footer_address_text)

input("Stop ..:")
driver.get("https://contacts.google.com/")
email_xpath = "//input[@id='identifierId']"
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, email_xpath).send_keys("sushenbiswasaga")

input("Stop ..:")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot log in to google with selenium webdrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76471550/cannot-log-in-to-google-with-selenium-webdrive)